# Saving any file type to binary, and then being able to read/convert/open that file type with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert and save a file with any file type (.pdf, .doc, .xls, etc., .png, etc) as binary data to MongoDB. But when that binary data is retrieved, I'm not sure that the normal file open, "rb" will preserve file type?

I'd like it so that the user can open the file and view it in it's original file type.
Forgive me if this is a common operation! I can't seem to find anything that fits explicitly as a solution.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: What exactly is your problem? I.e. which part of your implementation is not working?

Comment: All files are binary; the question is how those bytes are interpreted by whoever reads them. It *sounds* like you are trying to figure out what file extension should be added if you were to write the bytes out to disk again. That's not necessarily something that is (easily) accessible from binary data itself. The extension is a *guide* to indicate how to interpret the bytes.

Comment: thank you for the comments! In a broader sense, I'm attempting to have users be able to upload documents (any files of pretty much any file type) which would be saved to a MongoDB collection. I need the added functionality of being able to have user access those files and open them again-

Comment: You would just need to store the original filename, or at least the original extension, as a separate field in the database.